# How can I save Protected EAP credentials to the registry for a WiFi profile?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, windows-registry

This question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/878509/how-can-i-find-protected-eap-credentials-of-a-wireless-network-stored-on-windows) mentions how one can retrieve the Protected EAP credentials from the registry for a wlan profile.

Is it possible for me to save the PEAP credentials to this reg key in a similar way? We're looking to automate users connecting to a wlan network for which we already have a profile but we get a popup for the PEAP credentials currently.

It's suggested that it's possible [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48538649/1742551) but no detailed explanation.

FYI- Windows 10, if that makes a difference.

Comment: I think the prescribed way to make a Windows machine autojoin a WPA2-Enterprise network is to enable EAP-TLS on the authentication server and issue the Windows machine an EAP-TLS identity (.p12/.pfx, containing both a cert linking the machine's name to its private key, and the private key that goes with it). Then you store all that stuff in the cert store, not the registry.

Comment: @Spiff yes understood but this is for a specific time-sensitive scenario which unfortunately can't rely on a certificate being issued and delivered in a timely fashion. And is also based on existing WiFi infrastructure which can't be changed!