# Failed to find blob when retrieving username/password for connected WIFI with PEAP

Tags: wireless-networking, credentials, wpa2, 802.1x, peap

Hi I followed [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/878509/how-can-i-find-protected-eap-credentials-of-a-wireless-network-stored-on-windows), try to find a way to retrieve the username and password for a connected WPA2-Enterprice & PEAP protected WIFI.

I used [this tool](https://github.com/ash47/EnterpriseWifiPasswordRecover) to and ran it under system privilege.

The MSMUserData key was successfully outputted while it report an error on stage 2 of not finding blob, details are as follow:

```
D:\WIFI>EnterpriseWifiPasswordRecover.exe
{FDCBA1B2-685A-43FF-BE9E-1DA36EED2602}
Extracted stage1 for {FDCBA1B2-685A-43FF-BE9E-1DA36EED2602}
Failed to find an encrypted password blob :/
Found the following:
Domain:
Username:
Password:
```

My platform is Windows 10 for both computer. One of them are connected, and my target would be to put my other computer online while I do not know the username and password.

Comment: Do you know for sure that it uses a username and password as its credentials? PEAP also allows EAP-TLS user certificates (including ones stored on Smart Cards) to be used as the inner authentication method. "System credentials" — that's where your computer itself has Wi-Fi login credentials independent of any user — is much more likely to use TLS as the PEAP inner auth method rather than the username and password auth method.

Comment: @Spiff when I use the unconnected one it pops out for username and password. But I am not sure. I do not have the environment around and currently cannot do any tests :\