# How do I copy the credential of connected WIFI with WPA2-Enterprise and PEAP, and use it for connecting of other computer

Tags: networking, security

Hi I have a computer that connected to WIFI that is using WPA2-Enterprise and PEAP for credential (Win 10).

What I would like to do is to retrieve the relevant credential and using my other computer (Linux) to connect to the WIFI.

This is due to some essential tools and soft-wares on my Linux computer, and the company network engineer do not know how to connect it.

So I'm asking the possibility and, of course, the way of doing it.

Thanks a lot!!!!!

---

For more specific information, I followed [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/878509/how-can-i-find-protected-eap-credentials-of-a-wireless-network-stored-on-windows), try to find a way to retrieve the username and password for a connected WPA2-Enterprice & PEAP protected WIFI.

I used [this tool](https://github.com/ash47/EnterpriseWifiPasswordRecover) and ran it under system privilege.

The MSMUserData key was successfully outputted while it report an error on stage 2 of not finding blob, details are as follow:

```
D:\WIFI>EnterpriseWifiPasswordRecover.exe
{FDCBA1B2-685A-43FF-BE9E-1DA36EED2602}
Extracted stage1 for {FDCBA1B2-685A-43FF-BE9E-1DA36EED2602}
Failed to find an encrypted password blob :/
Found the following:
Domain:
Username:
Password:
```

Comment: Couldn't the company network engineer just provide you with new credentials?...

Comment: He doesn't know, it is standard installed of each computer. However, I already put a request and waiting for him. But this is out of the scope of the question..........

Comment: I'm utterly confused as to how the company's network admin doesn't know how the company's network devices connect. If he isn't the one issuing Wi-Fi credentials, then who is?? But someone might argue that the whole question is out of the scope of the website ("issues specific to corporate IT support and networks")...

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/878509/how-can-i-find-protected-eap-credentials-of-a-wireless-network-stored-on-windows – can you check if the tools described there work?

Comment: @user1686 he's following the program and standard from the tech provider (which also in the same group with our company). If we want to dig out the person who understand this and can do this, it may cost extensive time and effort of locating the right person (since the tech provider is not in the same country......). Anyway it is not the point of the question. I've checked the post long time ago, it does not work...

Comment: Is it using certificates? User/password + certificate? Only user/pass? Update the question with Relevant information.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart sorry for the late reply, my VPN crashed, it took me few days..... I do not know actually. May I kindly ask how should I verify it?? when I use a new computer to connect to the WIFI, it ask me to type in username/password. In the option, it shows "using the windows login name & password". If anything else you would like to know, please leave a msg. thanks a lot for the comment.